# Custom page tab is empty

Tags: facebook, tabs

My application used to work as custom tab on FB page, but currently it doesn't load when I click on tab, there is even no request to my server. Application itself is ok, I checked both secure and non-secure canvas URLs and page URLs.

Is there any way to find out what is going on? Logs/debug mode/etc?

Comment: can you post the link to the page tab app?

Comment: If you logged into Facebook as page this was related to Facebook's bug [Blank app page](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/141770462584785) which should be fixed now. Otherwise is something different...

Comment: I struggled with this problem for a while, and finally found a solution. Please see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304528/facebook-page-tab-is-empty-even-for-google-com/11307918#11307918

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome, right click on the fan page and select "Inspect Element".
Go to the Network panel and find out your server connection status. Click on it to get further information(headers, cookies, timing, etc).

My localhost server example:
[image: My localhost server example]

If you are using Firefox, you can install Firebug and do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few minutes ago. Turns out Facebook doesnt even try to load your iframe if the user is on FACEBOOK via HTTP, regardless of whether your application uses HTTPS.

So I changed my **web browser's** URL.

```
Old: http://www.facebook.com/<page>/app_<appID>
New: https://www.facebook.com/<page>/app_<appID>
```

**Edit**: What it seems that I originally had messed up was that in the application settings I had entered the HTTP URL in both the HTTP and the HTTPS fields. See http://d.pr/i/ARGF

This setting can be changed here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/**your app ID**/summary

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't even try to load your iframe ..."? I'm browsing Facebook with HTTP, and I see a hit to my server when I go to my app's tab.

Comment: Sorry, I realize now that my answer contained no tangible solution. I updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having this problem - in my case, the problem turned out to be a trailing space in my Secure Page Tab URL.

[image]

Make sure you have no leading or trailing spaces for any of the urls.

Very lame.

Comment: Wow. This got me too. (Didn't set the tab up though, I know better than to highlight extra whitespace :))