# Facebook page tab is empty even for google.com?

Tags: facebook

I've struggled with setting up a new Facebook page tab app for days. No matter what I do, I see a blank page (and believe me, I've read everything that google could find on the subject). Finally, I figured I just needed to see something working. So, I set up the most basic page tab app I could think of. All it does is tries to load google. Here's the setup: http://cl.ly/1h0R2c3O1T3i1T1B422d. There's nothing more to it.

You can try installing it to your own page: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab/?app_id=389862364403147&next=http://google.com

When you do, I suspect you'll see what I'm seeing...nothing (except for the familiar Facebook page header and footer)

Just in case Facebook isn't loading google.com 'cause they're at war, here's the setup for my real application: http://cl.ly/2J2t3n3I1D1N262M1s0J

Here's what I've tried:

1. Using a proxy to a publicly-accessible domain.
2. Making sure to use absolute URLs for Page Tab and Secure Page Tab
3. Sending the simplest page (the facebook_channel page I'm using now is just some text enclosed by html and body tags.
4. Not using html and body tags, and just using text.
5. Creating servers on https and http.

None of this works. Thanks in advance for your help. If I had hair, I'd be ripping it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When you do, I suspect you'll see what I'm seeing...nothing (except for the familiar Facebook page header and footer)

Get a better test browser then :-)

Opera gives me the following message,

> Error
>
> https://google.com/
>
> The website does not permit its content to be displayed in a frame. It must be displayed in a separate window.

– which was to be expected, since Google sends the HTTP header `X-Frame-Options:    SAMEORIGIN`

Regarding your problem with your own app page – check your server logs, to see if the request even comes up there; and if so, how it is answered.

Then check if there’s a problem with your SSL certificate – Firefox for example won’t let you add an exception for your local test site if it’s displayed in an iframe (should show a warning message though). Can you reach your test page outside of Facebook, stand-alone?

Comment: you are now my favorite person on the face of the planet! I'm a little frustrated that I didn't see an error like that from Chrome, Safari or FF. In any case, the problem for my real app page was the same problem with the Google app. For those out there using Django, you'll want to use the csrf_exempt and xframe_options_exempt decorators on the views you're using to serve Facebook requests. This is assuming you're using CsrfViewMiddleware and XFrameOptionsMiddleware.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that Chrome does (and probably the other browsers do) display an error when trying to load a page blocked by the X-Frame-Options policy. To see it, however, you need to open the javascript console.

Comment: To my surprise, IE displays a fairly good error message as well, not just a blank page. (Of course, I did only see that after reading the answer from CBroe here, because I was only testing with Chrome and FF before.)