# Facebook for android not sending notification?

Tags: android, facebook

I am using **facebook** android sdk for sending an application request in android but when I am using hackbook for android demo project its sending notification but if I use my own application id gives by facebook then application doe not send notification.

Comment: are you 100% your app id is correct?

Comment: yes that is same and how can i look my application made in facebook may be possible that my application didn't created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to Facebook.com,
- Click on Developer at the bottom of the page,
- Click on Apps on the menu at the top

Check that the App ID is definitely the same as the one in your app.

Comment: my app is there and the id is same i am using what can be the problem is there any permision or signature that is specific to an app.and if i use the app id of deme project "hackbook" then its sending notofication with keyword as "xxx invited you in hackbook for android ". id want my app name there

Comment: is your app authorised with the Android Key Hash?

Comment: what kind of notification is it?

Comment: what you could do is post on the user's wall from your app?

Comment: no i have to to with notification. is it possible that when i click on notification then that redirect user to app page where i could post an external link? currently my app page is showing blank.

Comment: sorry i'm a little confused, you are sending a request with your app, the user has to authorise the app, then what?

Comment: when i send app request to someone assume you then you recieve a notification "abc invited you to use app" then you click on notification. right,then when you click on notification then you should be redirected to app's play.google link. understand?

Comment: have you got an app detail page?

Comment: no that is the problem? i am getting an empty page so how fill that page?how can i get my app detail page .please help

Comment: well as far as i can see, without the detail page, you are not redirected anywhere. please also accept my answer as your original question was answered :)

Comment: ok i will. and how can i get my detail page? iam getting an blank page now?

Comment: go to your app in the developers area, it'll say Edit Settings, then then on the left it'll say App Detail

Comment: i did it but its not showing when i am clicking on notification.

Comment: when receiver receives notification then he click on that notification then he should be redirected to app detail page but it showing blank app detail page.

Comment: something on your app detail page isn't right, check the URLs

Comment: where should be the url of the app detail page or something else?

Comment: where to put that "url" of blank page? i mean in which field?

Comment: https://apps.facebook.com/euro_game/?fb_source=appcenter&fb_appcenter=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304528/facebook-page-tab-is-empty-even-for-google-com/11307918#11307918 check this question